# NPE when trying to put a word in an array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

As the title says, I'm getting an NPE when trying to put a word in my String Array.

The array is declared outside of the method

```
String[] spelersLijst;

    aantalSpelers = Input.readInt();

    for (int g = 0; g < aantalSpelers; g++) {
        String naamSpeler = "Speler " + (g+1);
        spelersLijst [g] = naamSpeler;
    }
```

I'm sure it's just a minor thing I'm missing but I'm not really good with those kind of things. Thanks in advance

Edit: The error is in the following line:

```
spelersLijst [g] = naamSpeler;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to insert elements into an array which isn't initialized yet. you have to **initialize** your array before you insert elements in it.

```
String[] spelersLijst;
aantalSpelers = Input.readInt();
   spelersLijst= new String[aantalSpelers ];
for (int g = 0; g < aantalSpelers; g++) {
    String naamSpeler = "Speler " + (g+1);
    spelersLijst [g] = naamSpeler;
}
```